# Change application insights instance for api management

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I am using application insights for logging and monitoring in our production environment. Today our API Management is connected to one of our application insights "instances". We have some alerts connected to our APIM.

I would like to change the current application insights to another one, is this possible without disturbing anything else? Has anyone does this before?

I was planning to change the instance here: APIM -> APIs -> All APIs -> Settings and change the destination.

Screenshot from APIM:

[image: apim-applicationinsights]

I have done the same change in our test environment and that went fine, but we also do not have any alerts there.

Comment: If it points to a different Application Insights resource it means that whatever is configured on the current one will not be applicable (historical data, configured alerts, dashboards, etc.). They will need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

By default APIM management will use its built in analytics to get default data with metrics and alerts without Application Insights. If you have created an alert based on default metrics, then changing Application Insight won’t affect that Alert

**But as you have added Application Insights at your API level and triggered an alert based on the API telemetry data sent to application Insights. If you change the Application insights resource at API’s level for all API’s or a single API you would need to create a new alert based on API telemetry data as the data will be routed to the another application insight resource.**

I created one APIM management instance without connecting Application Insights resource to it, It still monitors basic Metrics with default built in analytics and alerts can be created based on those Metrics -

[image]

No Application Insights connected :-

[image]

Default Metrics and Alerts :-

[image]

[image]

I have created another APIM instance where I have added one Application Insights logging at API level :-

[image]

[image]

API telemetry logs sent to Application Insights :-

[image]

Above valleyai application Insights is receiving telemetry data from APIM instance if you have created an alert based on this Application Insights, and you change your Application insight resource to another in APIM, You need to update your Alerts and new data will be sent to the newly connected Application Insight resource.

[image]

Changed API level logging to valleyAI2 application insights:-

[image]

valleyAI2 started receiving telemetry data :-

[image]

New Alert is created and enabled at new application Insight resource connected to APIM :-

[image]

The Alerts needs to be created separately if application Insights are connected to API’s at Application Insights level.